# Want to Insert complete JSON response data (dictionary) in Sqlite and retrieve with dictionary response

Tags: ios, json, sqlite

I have tried with multiple solution like
1) Save as NSData
2) Save as NSString
3) tried with NSKeyedUnarchiver

Nothing will work in my case. Check attached JSON Data

Code for saving and retrieving data from sqlite

```
- (BOOL)saveBookData:(NSString *)bookID bookName:(NSString*)bookNames bookTitle:(NSString*)bookTitle valueArr:(NSDictionary *)valueArr
  {
   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
    NSData *theDictionaryData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:valueArr];
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into bookDetails(bookID, bookName, bookTitle, valueArr) values (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",bookID,bookNames,bookTitle, theDictionaryData];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);

   // sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [bookID UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [bookNames UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [bookTitle UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    //sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [valueArr UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 4, (__bridge const void *)(theDictionaryData) , -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
    //sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return NO;
}
```

retrive -

```
-(NSMutableArray*)findAllBook
{
resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

sqlite3 *database2;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database2) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select bookID, bookName, bookTitle, valueArr from bookDetails"];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database2, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSString *_savePdfID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            NSString *_savePdfName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *_savePdfText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            // NSString *_savePdfDetails = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            NSData *retrieveData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 4) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 4)];

            //NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:retrieveData];
            //NSLog(@"dict data is %@",dictionary);

            [_dataDictionary2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_savePdfID] forKey:@"savedBOOKID"];
            [_dataDictionary2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_savePdfName] forKey:@"savedBOOKName"];
            [_dataDictionary2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_savePdfText] forKey:@"savedBOOKText"];
            [_dataDictionary2 setObject:retrieveData forKey:@"savedBOOKDetail"];

            [resultArray addObject:_dataDictionary2];
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database2);

return resultArray;
 }
```

Code which I am using in my Controller

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[[PDFManager getSharedInstance]findAllBook]);
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[PDFManager getSharedInstance]findAllBook]valueForKey:@"savedBOOKDetail"];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
```

Guy I have tried multiple times but still facing problem always getting null value when retrive,Can you please provide some solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code using the debugger? Is the execution path what you expect? No one can really help since you've provided no details about what is actually happening.

Comment: Yes sir I debug with every step and what I expect i mention I want to save my json data so later I can retrieve and use them. NSData added perfectly but it is showing null value at time of retrieving so am i wrong in the code What else I should explain?

Comment: I asking if the code you posted is actually doing what you expect. Step through, line by line. Does each line run as expected? Does each line give the proper result? How do you know the `NSData` is added perfectly?

Comment: I am printing my data and I have also downloaded the container and check the db.Yes I go through line by line else I am not going to ask.Did you get some idea else it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code. But the main cause of your problem is the column index numbers for your `valueArr` column. When you attempt to read the data, you use the wrong index.

Your query is:

> Select bookID, bookName, bookTitle, valueArr from bookDetails

`bookdID` is index 0 and `valueArr` is index 3. All of the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions use a zero based index even though all of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions use a one based index.

This line:

```
NSData *retrieveData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 4) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 4)];
```

needs to be:

```
NSData *retrieveData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 3) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 3)];
```

In addition to this, you need to fix all of the problems in your `saveBookData` method. You don't close the database if it's opened. You don't do any error checking when preparing the statement. You don't finalize the statement if it's prepared.

Your `findAllBook` is better but it still has issues. You close the database even if it doesn't open. You finalize the statement even if it isn't prepared. And you should add calls to `sqlite3_errmsg` when any error check fails so you know why it failed.

Comment: Thanks buddy, Index value I forgot to change but I am using 3 and I am getting the NSData  (<3c363237 30366336 39203733 37343330 ). below line always giving null value. [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]

Comment: `[arr objectAtIndex:0]` is already a dictionary. Why are you trying to unarchive it?

Comment: No, That is dictionary archive data. so after getting data i have to unarchive to get details.   NSMutableArray *arr = [[[PDFManager getSharedInstance]findAllBook]valueForKey:@"savedBOOKDetail"]; is this fine?

Comment: But you are already unarchiving the data from the database in the `findAllBook` method. You don't need another unarchive after calling `findAllBook`. Regardless of that, I answered your original question. If you have further issues, you should close this question by accepting the answer and possibly posting a new question with details specific to the new issue.

Comment: My unarchive code is commented in above code,I have try to use over there and save button that was not worked.It is fine still I am on same thing.So I will close When I feel to close this thanks for help buddy